# Custom height for tableviewcell with uiimageview

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a uitableview which has a uiimageview. It's height and width(always square) is calculated by auto layout set in storyboard and working fine. But when I run my app height of tableviewcell is not updated. I have tried following code to fix it:

```
tblvwPosts?.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tblvwPosts?.estimatedRowHeight = 300

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HomeTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell

    cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()

    return cell
}
```

But after adding above code height of the tableviewcell is changed to 44px.
By the way I am looking to have row similar to instagram/facebook where there will be a square image with width/height equal to device width and below it will be some labels and buttons.

Regards
Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom cell, you can use this method to force your cell row height to custom value;

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat 
{
    return 100.0;//Choose your custom row height
}
```

or you can simply change the value with this code;

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = 100.0
```

Comment: I am looking to do it by auto layout not by coding, otherwise there will be many conditions for all the sizes of iphone

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad of your tableVC try setting the estimated height to the height in storyboard and then resetting it to automatic dimension

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimention
}
```

Comment: I have checked but I could not find estimated height for tableview or tableviewcell in storyboard. I am only able to set it in coding

Comment: It doesn't say estimated but if you select the cell and go to the inspector, there is row height

Comment: In your code, you first set it to auto dimension and back to the estimated row height. I don't think that's the order you want, first get the estimate then let it calculate the auto dimension accordingly

Comment: no it is still not working, I have set above code and in row height in storyboard it is 300 but I am getting row with height of 44(default row height)